# How to connect to the Db?

Tags: c#, rest, amazon-rds

Can't get response from server after deploying my app to the AWS.

I just created small REST server app from [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). 
        Also I tried to  use UseSqlServer with copying connection string from Amazon Db.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<GameContext>(opt =>

    opt.UseSqlServer(/* AmazonDbConnectionString */);

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Seems like it works, when I launch it on my local machine: I insert data into DbTable and see changes using Sql Server Management Studio.
But it doesn't work when I publish it to AWS: I can load default ValueController and get response [value1, value2]. So no doubts that app is working, but can't get response of DbDataController.

Also I tried to follow [Amazon tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.rds.html#dotnet-rds-create) and use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings but it returns null always.

```
[HttpGet("connection")]
public ActionResult<string> Get()
{
      return "ConnectionString: " + GameContext.GetRDSConnectionString();
}
...
public static string GetRDSConnectionString()
{
      var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
      string dbname = appConfig["RDS_DB_NAME"];
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbname)) return null;
      string username = appConfig["RDS_USERNAME"];
      string password = appConfig["RDS_PASSWORD"];
      string hostname = appConfig["RDS_HOSTNAME"];
      string port = appConfig["RDS_PORT"];
      return "Data Source=" + hostname + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + username + ";Password=" + password + ";";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used it for get value from Appsetting and its work for me:

```
//Appsetting
"ApplicationConfigurations": {
    "SendSmsActive": "true"
  }
//Controller
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public HomeController( IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public string GetConfig()
        {
             string str = _configuration["ApplicationConfigurations:SendSmsActive"].ToString();
        }
  }
```